# How to batch write with tensorboard?

Tags: tensorboard

Imagine I have a numpy array of size `(T, k)` where `k` is the size of one sample and `T` is the number of samples.

I use tensorboard to write this `(T, k)` numpy array to a tf event file to visualize `k` different plots. Each plot is a 2d plot where the x-axis indexes the number of samples `t=1,...,T` and the y-axis shows the value of one dimension out of `k` dimension across the samples.

To write the tf event file, I need two loop: one over the `k` dimensions and one over the `T` dimensions since iirc, tensorboard only allows writing a single scalar at once, and does not have a "batch" mode.

As you can image, this is quite slow. Any tips on speeding this up?